# Kube-proxy was not found in my rancher cluster

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, kube-proxy

My Rancher cluster is setup around 3 weeks. Everything works fine. But there is one problem while installing MetalLB. I found there is no kubeproxy in my cluster. Even there no kube-proxy pod in every node. I could not follow installation guide to setup config map of kube-proxy

For me, it is really strange to have a cluster without kubeproxy

My setup for rancher cluster is below:

```
Cluster Provider: RKE
Provision and Provision : Use existing nodes and create a cluster using RKE 
Network Plugin : canal
```

Maybe something I misunderstand. I can discover nodeport and ClusterIP in service correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I find my kibe-proxy. It is process of host not docker container.

In Racher, we should edit cluster.yml to put extra args for kube-proxy. Rather will apply in every node of cluster automatically.

```sh
root     3358919  0.1  0.0 749684 42564 ?        Ssl  02:16   0:00 kube-proxy --proxy-mode=ipvs --ipvs-scheduler=lc --ipvs-strict-arp=true --cluster-cidr=10.42.0.0/16
```